# How to install Wordpress next to existing CMS?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, content-management-system, typo3-6.2.x

My client wants to experiment around with Wordpress on a server that they have currently a Typo3 CMS running on. I'm supposed to set it up, without making the old website unusable.

Current website is e.g. www.test.com and that shouldn't change -
It doesn't really matter how to get to that wordpress site but I guess something like www.test.com/test_wordpress would be nice.

The Server is running on `Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.6 i686)` and the PHP Version is `5.3.10-1ubuntu3.25`

I'm afraid the newest Wordpress can't run on this PHP Version.(?)
But if I update it I think the old Website would get a lot of problems.

Is there a way to run multiple PHP Versions on that Server?
If not and if there's no way to run Wordpress on the old PHP version I'd rather just get an older release because it should be done quickly and is just for playing around.

How should I install Wordpress (just the basic steps in order not to overwrite and break anything from the old website would be enough)?

I installed Wordpress on a virtual server (with Vagrant) before, but since the environment is different this time I'm asking here for help what I have to watch out for in order not to break any existing functionality of the main Typo3 CMS currently running on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress will work with your PHP version

please check

https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Note: If you are in a legacy environment where you only have older PHP or MySQL versions, WordPress also works with PHP 5.2.4+ and MySQL 5.0+, but these versions have

Comment: Thanks for the info, but that doesn't answer my question on the steps of installing it alongside the existing cms

Comment: You can install Wordpress in subfolder and just include one file from wp 
include.php to use all wordpress function

You can use get_post and all function of wordpress in your CMS.

Comment: yes, I just figured that out too :)
Now I'm struggling with creating a new db for wp because I can't login with mysql -u root and idk what password I need for it, the old Typo3 has 2 DBs right now but they're not meant for root as it seems but for sepcific users...I have no idea how to do this now...

Comment: I figured out the problem, there was no db-user named 'root' that's why I couldn't access the db :D